# how to find the next n day returns if specific condition matches in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Question: what if the specific condition (df[df["per"]<-4) meets how to get the next n day returns in python

Comment: please add a minimally reproducable example, then I can help you see: (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data, try to provide [either code to generate the dataframe or the `print`ed dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) − or at least a few rows that allow to reproduce your problem.